# Sorting object properties by property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an JavaScript object:

```
var objs = {'1':2, '2':3, '3':1, '4':2};
```

How can I sort the properties by the value of numbers in JavaScript?

I know about `sort(a,b)`, but that only seems to work on strings and numbers. Do I need to add a `toString()` method to my objects?

Comment: `objs` is array or object?

Comment: please add the array.

Comment: sorry i mean objs is object

Comment: AFAIK you can't sort object properties.

Comment: why do you want to sort an object? Even if you build an object with presorted properties, it is not guaranteed that they will display in the same order in the future

Comment: @evolutionxbox, you can with a new object, but not index like values.

Comment: i want to get 
arr = [3,1,4,2] from that object. how to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object does not (always) follow the insertion order. So it can't be guaranty that you always get same output. For sorting you can use either **array** or **Map** to maintain the order. For more info please see [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

According to question: `var objs = {'1':2, '2':3, '3':1, '4':2};` How can I sort them by the value of numbers in JavaScript? You can do as follows

```
var objs = {
  '1': 2,
  '2': 3,
  '3': 1,
  '4': 2
};
var map = new Map(Object.entries(objs));
var sorted = new Map(Array.from(map).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]));
console.log(sorted);
```